# Rabbitmq /usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf Missing

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I just installed RabbitMQ on an AWS EC2-Instance (CentOS) using the following,

```
sudo yum install erlang

sudo yum install rabbitmq-server
```

I was then able to successfully turn it on using,

```
sudo chkconfig rabbitmq-server on

sudo /sbin/service rabbitmq-server start

...and

sudo /sbin/service rabbitmq-server stop

sudo sudo rabbitmq-server run in foreground;
```

But now I'm trying to modify the `/usr/local/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-env.conf` file so I can change the `NODE_IP_ADDRESS` but the file is no where to be found.

No rabbitmq folder under,

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 sbin]$ ls /usr/local/etc
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 sbin]$
```

There's a rabbitmq folder under `/etc` but there's nothing in it,

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 rabbitmq]$ pwd
/etc/rabbitmq
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 rabbitmq]$ ls
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 rabbitmq]$
```

And the only thing in my environment variables for rabbitmq is this

```
[ec2-user@ip-0-0-0-0 rabbitmq]$ printenv | grep rabbit
PWD=/etc/rabbitmq
```

I was able to go to the location of the rabbitmq logs and find this information,

```
root@ip-0-0-0-0
[/var/log/rabbitmq]# pwd
/var/log/rabbitmq
root@ip-0-0-0-0
[/var/log/rabbitmq]# ls -al
total 20
drwxr-x---  2 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Jun  7 17:28 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root     4096 Jun  7 17:23 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 3638 Jun  7 17:33 rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0.log
-rw-r--r--  1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    0 Jun  7 17:25 rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0-sasl.log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 Jun  7 17:28 shutdown_err
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       65 Jun  7 17:28 shutdown_log
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root        0 Jun  7 17:25 startup_err
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root      385 Jun  7 17:28 startup_log


cat rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0.log

=INFO REPORT==== 7-Jun-2018::17:29:01 ===
node           : rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
config file(s) : (none)
cookie hash    : W/uaA12+PF+KOIbCmdKTkw==
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0
```

And `/var/lib/rabbitmq` contains this,

```
[/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia]# cd /var/lib/rabbitmq/
root@ip-0-0-0-0
[/var/lib/rabbitmq]# ls
mnesia
```

And

```
[/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia]# pwd
/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia
root@ip-0-0-0-0
[/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia]# ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Jun  7 17:29 .
drwxr-x--- 3 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Jun  7 17:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Jun  7 17:35 rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    5 Jun  7 17:28 rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0.pid
drwxr-xr-x 2 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4096 Jun  7 17:29 rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0-plugins-expand
root@ip-0-0-0-0
```

And,

```
[/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0]# pwd
/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0
root@ip-0-0-0-0
[/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@ip-0-0-0-0]# ls -al
total 100
drwxr-xr-x 4 rabbitmq rabbitmq  4096 Jun  7 17:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 rabbitmq rabbitmq  4096 Jun  7 17:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    59 Jun  7 17:29 cluster_nodes.config
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   160 Jun  7 17:35 DECISION_TAB.LOG
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    99 Jun  7 17:35 LATEST.LOG
drwxr-xr-x 2 rabbitmq rabbitmq  4096 Jun  7 17:29 msg_store_persistent
drwxr-xr-x 2 rabbitmq rabbitmq  4096 Jun  7 17:29 msg_store_transient
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq    29 Jun  7 17:29 nodes_running_at_shutdown
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  1123 Jun  7 17:29 rabbit_durable_exchange.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq  2422 Jun  7 17:32 rabbit_durable_exchange.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq     8 Jun  7 17:25 rabbit_durable_queue.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq     8 Jun  7 17:25 rabbit_durable_route.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq     8 Jun  7 17:25 rabbit_runtime_parameters.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq     3 Jun  7 17:29 rabbit_serial
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   344 Jun  7 17:35 rabbit_user.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   193 Jun  7 17:29 rabbit_user_permission.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   461 Jun  7 17:35 rabbit_user_permission.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   134 Jun  7 17:29 rabbit_vhost.DCD
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   289 Jun  7 17:32 rabbit_vhost.DCL
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq 19108 Jun  7 17:25 schema.DAT
-rw-r--r-- 1 rabbitmq rabbitmq   233 Jun  7 17:25 schema_version
```

And last but not least apparently the logs say there isn't a config file,

```
[/var/log/rabbitmq]# cat rabbit\@ip-0-0-0-0.log | grep config
config file(s) : (none)
config file(s) : (none)
```

RabbitMQ Version: `{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.1.5"}`

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm surprised I didn't see any errors when I started the `rabbitmq-server`. Do I just create the config files myself?

**UPDATE:**

I was setting up a cluster environment for my Apache Airflow and so I was configuring it with the CeleryExecutor and setting up the Queue to be RabbitMQ. Turns out I'm running my EC2-Instance with Amazon Linux 1 which doesn't include [systemd](https://serverfault.com/questions/889248/how-to-enable-systemd-on-amazon-linux-ami) so I wasn't able to get RabbitMQ properly installed. Had I made my server using Amazon Linux 2 or Ubuntu, or any other Linux that doesn't suck I could have potentially gotten further in installing RabbitMQ and getting it to work with Airflow. So I went on to using AWS SQS for my queue and then I ran [into this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765423/airflow-cluster-celery-sqs-airflow-worker-hub-object-has-no-attribute?noredirect=1#comment88550722_50765423). So by now I've wasted over two and a half days trying to just get a queue to work with Celery and Airflow and I read [this article](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow/pull/63) which says that Airbnb (the creators of Airflow) are using Celery with Redis as their Queue. So I tried it out and it literally took me three minutes to do and it's working flawlessly.... All I did was download Redis using `sudo yum install redis` then bam I had Redis installed. [I started Redis using](https://redis.io/topics/quickstart) `redis-server`. Then I changed my `airflow.cfg` broker_url field to `broker_url = redis://`, ran `airflow initdb`, restarted the scheduler `airflow scheduler`, then started a worker `airflow worker` and BAM my DAGs started running using the Redis queue and CeleryExecutor. **HALLELUJAH just use Redis as your queue....**

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the latest version of RabbitMQ (`3.7.5`) and Erlang `19.3` or later. Version `3.1.5` is very, very, very old. Please see [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-rpm.html) for instructions on how to install a recent RMQ on an rpm-based distro.

After that, you will create `rabbitmq-env.conf` yourself.